# How to get filelist and use the filename as input for string manipulation (duplicate checking) & condition using batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to create a windows batch file that will:

1st: List files in current directory and output to a filenamelist (Filelist_[YYY][MM][DD][hh][mm]ss])

2nd: From the given filenamelist, read each line as an input for 3rd step

3rd: Read the first line of the file and extract 7th, 9th, and and 14th string.

```
Delimiter can be "~", "*" and "^"
```

4th: Assign 7th as ISAsender variable, 9th as ISAreceiver, and 14th string as ISActrlnum.

5th: Redirect the echoed variables to a single logfile (EDI.log).

EDIT:
6th: Check ISAsender's CNtable.txt (Ex. AP_CNtable.txt for ISA's APPLESND, SS_CNtable for SAMSUNGSND) if ISActrlnum already exists or duplicate. Initially CNtable.txt contains dumped values of ISActrlnum (control numbers).

```
a. If there is duplicate control number found, exit with error message and output to Dupfile.txt as well as the ISActrlnum in issue. Move file to EXCEPT folder.
b. If not duplicate, insert ISActrlnum to CNtable.txt then proceed to 7th.
```

7th: Use IF condition for ISAsender and ISAreceiver to move the file to a correspoinding folder. 
8th: Repeat 3rd-7th until 2nd step reaches EOF or finished reading each lines.

Example: From a given Filelist_20141022010101, FileName.txt contains the following having "~" as delimiter:

```
ISA~00~          ~00~          ~ZZ~APPLESND       ~14~APPLERCV       ~130214~2300~U~00401~000000001~0~T~>
GS~FA~APPLESND~APPLERCV~20130214~2300~810~X~004010
ST~997~131250001
AK1~SC~1809
AK9~A~1~1~1
SE~4~131250001
GE~1~810
IEA~1~000000001
```

while CNtable.txt contains:

```
000000004
000000002
000000003
000000005
```

Since ISActrlnum=000000001 does not exist in CNtable.txt, it will update CNtable.txt by appending ISActrlnum. Here only conditional statements for the ISAsender and ISAreceiver will be utilized.
So if ISAsender=APPLESND and ISAreceiver=APPLERCV move the curent file (FileName.txt) to specific directory such as C:\VP\APPLE.
Same logic for the next filename inside Filelist_20141022010101.

I was able to write code below but don't know how to get the filename from FORFILES and use it again as variable input in the FOR LOOP.

```
REM FileReceiver.bat
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set Min=%dt:~10,2%
set Sec=%dt:~12,2%

set TIMESTAMP=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%

C:
cd "C:\VP"

FORFILES /P "C:\VP" >"FLIST.%TIMESTAMP%"


set first=1
for /f "tokens=7 delims=~" %%a in (FileName.txt) do (
      if %first%==1 (
           set first=0
       set ISAsender=%%a
       echo %ISAsender%

      )
)

set first=1
for /f "tokens=9 delims=~" %%b in (FileName.txt) do (
      if %first%==1 (
           set first=0
       set ISAreceiver=%%b
       echo %ISAreceiver%

      )
)
set first=1
for /f "tokens=14 delims=~" %%c in (FileName.txt) do (
      if %first%==1 (
           set first=0
       set ISActrlnum=%%c
       echo %ISActrlnum%
      )
)


if %ISAsender%=="APPLESND" if %ISAreceiver=="APPLERCV"    (
    move FileName.txt "C:\VP\APPLE"
    )

if %ISAsender%=="SAMSUNGSND" if %ISAreceiver=="SAMSUNGRCV"    (
    move FileName.txt "C:\VP\SAMSUNG"
    )
```

Can anyone help me to satisfy the requirement without having to call another batch file that checks the duplicate control numbers (ISActrlnum) ?
As much as possible I want the whole code in a single bat file. Please bear with my lengthy description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to setup the entire environment you have on your computer to recode your batch file, but I think I got it.

Read the comments - the lines starting with `rem` - to understand the batch file and adapt it to your environment if this necessary.

```
@echo off
REM FileReceiver.bat
setlocal

rem Get current date and time as local time independent on Windows region settings.
for /F "tokens=2 delims==." %%T in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set "dt=%%T"

rem Reformat the date and time strong to wanted format.
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%"
set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%"
set "Min=%dt:~10,2%"
set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
set "TimeStamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"

rem Define name of the list file containing current date and time in name.
set "ListFile=FLIST_%TimeStamp%.lst"

rem Change directory (and drive).
cd /D "C:\VP"

rem Create the list file which is good here as the list of files changes
rem while running this batch file and therefore it is better to work with
rem a list file instead of running a FOR directly for each file in the
rem directory. The list file is not included in this list as it either does
rem not exist at all or it has wrong file extension as only *.txt files are
rem listed by command DIR. The log file EDI.log has also wrong file extension.
dir *.txt /A-D /B /ON >%ListFile%

rem It might be useful to delete the log file from a previous run.
if exist EDI.log del EDI.log

rem Process each file in the list file.
for /F "delims=" %%F in ( %ListFile% ) do call :ProcessFile "%%F"

rem Delete the list file as not needed anymore. It could be also kept.
del %ListFile%

rem Exit batch file.
endlocal
goto :EOF


:ProcessFile
rem The parameter passed from first FOR is the file name in double quotes.
set "FileName=%~1"

rem Ignore the files *_CNtable.txt and Dupfile.txt in same directory.
rem Command goto :EOF just exits here from subroutine ProcessFile.
if "%FileName%"=="AP_CNtable.txt" goto :EOF
if "%FileName%"=="SS_CNtable.txt" goto :EOF
if "%FileName%"=="Dupfile.txt" goto :EOF

rem Get 7th, 9th and 14th element from first line of current file.
for /f "usebackq tokens=7,9,14 delims=~*^" %%a in ( "%FileName%" ) do (
   set "ISAsender=%%a"
   set "ISAreceiver=%%b"
   set "ISActrlnum=%%c"
   goto WriteToLogFile
)

:WriteToLogFile
rem Remove all spaces as ISAsender and ISAreceiver have
rem usually spaces appended at end according to example
rem text. Then write file name and the 3 values to log file.
set "ISAsender=%ISAsender: =%"
set "ISAreceiver=%ISAreceiver: =%"
set "ISActrlnum=%ISActrlnum: =%"
echo %FileName%,%ISAsender%,%ISAreceiver%,%ISActrlnum%>>EDI.log

if "%ISAsender%"=="APPLESND" (
    rem Check for ISA control number in file AP_CNtable.txt.
    %SystemRoot%\System32\Findstr.exe /X /M /C:%ISActrlnum% AP_CNtable.txt >nul
    if not errorlevel 1 goto Duplicate

    echo %ISActrlnum%>>AP_CNtable.txt

    if "%ISAreceiver%"=="APPLERCV" (
        move /Y "%FileName%" "APPLE"
        echo Moved %FileName% to directory APPLE.
    )
)

if "%ISAsender%"=="SAMSUNGSND" (
    rem Check for ISA control number in file SS_CNtable.txt.
    %SystemRoot%\System32\Findstr.exe /X /M /C:%ISActrlnum% SS_CNtable.txt >nul
    if not errorlevel 1 goto Duplicate

    echo %ISActrlnum%>>SS_CNtable.txt

    if "%ISAreceiver%"=="SAMSUNGRCV" (
        move /Y "%FileName%" "SAMSUNG"
        echo Moved %FileName% to directory SAMSUNG.
    )
)
rem Exit the subroutine ProcessFile.
goto :EOF

:Duplicate
rem This ISA control number is already present in file *_CNtable.txt.
echo Duplicate control %ISActrlnum% found in file %FileName%.
echo %ISActrlnum%,%FileName%>>Dupfile.txt

rem Exit the subroutine ProcessFile.
goto :EOF
```

I'm not sure why the list file must have the current date and time in name, but perhaps you want to keep it for some unknown reason. In this case it would be necessary to delete 2 lines in code above - the line with command `del %ListFile%` and the comment line above.

**Updated** batch code on 2014-10-07 according to changes on point 6 in question.

Comment: Thanks @Mofi Ill try the codes and let you know. The timestamps are for tracking purposes so I would know when did I receive the file or if I receive the file sent by external server.

Comment: Hi @Mofi how do I tweak it in such a manner it would check first the ISAsenderID before it checks duplicates only for that ID, thus there would be CNtable.txt for each ISAsenderID initially. I've updated requirement number 6 for this. Thanks for your help.